# Perfmon Total Counters: 32-Bit Wrap Around?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, perfmon

For counters in Windows Server 2008 R2 that count the total (instead of rate) at what number do they wrap around to zero? In this particular case I am interested in `\Web Service(_Total)\Total Get Requests`. Are they always maybe 32bit or 64bit. Or maybe it depends on if it is a 32bit or 64bit OS (in this case, R2 so has to be 64)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a 32bit unsigned Integer.

Reference: [Win32_PerformattedData_W3SVC_WebService -> TotalGetRequests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394298%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Normally it will be an unsigned 32 bit (on 32-bit system) so 2^32 = 4294967296. So the range is 0-4294967295.

Comment: Any references on that? That would be my *guess* as well, but rather find out for sure instead of a bug creeping up on me by the time I forget all about this.

Comment: Whoever writes the code that publishes the counter can decide on the size, 32 or 64 bit; so there's really no 'normally' about it. It will be dependent on the particular counter in question. It's also actually pretty unlikely that it would be different on a 64 bit OS, it's more likely that you'd decide to use a 64bit counter if the count would otherwise wrap 'regularly'.